# Spying on canvas context methods with Cypress

Tags: cypress

I am spying on an element that has a canvas, which draws a canvas and clears it every second with `context.clearRect(...)`, and I'm trying to spy on that with cypress:

```js
describe('canvas clears', () => {
  let context;
  let spy;

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visitHome();
    cy.sendStudyUpdateWithSingleSeries(seriesWithNoFrames); // this places the canvas on the screen
    cy.get('[data-testid=data]').then(([canvas]) => {
      context = (canvas as HTMLCanvasElement).getContext('2d');
      spy = cy.spy(context, 'clearRect');
    });
  });
  it('works', () => {
    expect(spy).to.be.called;
  });
});
```

Cypress makes its way throught he `beforeEach` section and immediately goes on to the test which immediately fails. However, after the failure is printed, the Spy shows up as called, and indeed updates its call count every second. But the test isn't looking for it anymore, I guess?

How do I make this spy work?

(note: I get the same results with `expect(spy).to.have.been.called`)

[image]

Comment: The assertion seems to fail before the SPY-1 log comes through. Try figuring a way to increase the assertions timeout: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Timeouts. Wish I could help more but am in a rush and haven't used Cypress in a while.